# pytables: How to remove data from reopened file

Tags: copy, edit, hdf5, pytables

I have a problem modifying a pytables-file.
I want to load the file and remove an raw-image from it. As I could find out removing data from pytables-files is not too easy. I only found the ".remove_node()" method. But when I open the file in write-mode it gets overwritten with a new/empty pytables-file. When I open it in read-mode I can't change the file obviously.

What am I doing wrong here? How is the method supposed to be used? Do I have to open a new file and copy the data?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Didn't see I have to use "r+" / "a" mode instead of "w"(write)...